# Why Mysql queries goes to statistics?

Tags: mysql, database

I just want to know the exact reason why Mysql queries goes to statistics.I do not have any idea what to do now? I have tried several articles.

Comment: What do you mean by "statistics"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TheImpaler statistics means the statistics of the table created by Mysql